# how to change virtualbox keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, virtualbox, customization, shortcuts

In virtualbox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> is the shortcut to reset the virtual machine. But I use it for testing web-sites on IE, and I seem to be hard-wired to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh web-pages in a browser. I keep accidentally resetting virtualbox and having to wait while it books again!! So is there some way to change the keyboard shortcuts in virtualbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the 'host key':

`file -> preferences -> input`

Change the Host Key to something other than ctrl.

~~edit~~

NOTE: the host key can be something like 'Right Ctrl'.  The left control key acts normally, and the right key is used as the host key.

Comment: As a note, that's the file menu of the main UI, and you can "hot change" it while the guest is running (at least in windows).